# Making new sub-directories using curly brace expansion

Tags: bash, command-line

Given two directories; dira and dirb, how can I make subdirectories using curly brace expansion in mkdir command?

For instance, I have tried: `mkdir -p {dira, dirb}/sub`. This results in two new directories called `{dira,` and `dirb}`. Instead, I would like instead to have `dira/sub` and `dirb/sub`.

I am running the following version:
`GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: Just delete the space after the comma: `mkdir -p {dira,dirb}/sub`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ mkdir -p {dira,dirb}/sub

$ find .
.
./dirb
./dirb/sub
./dira
./dira/sub
```

Using `GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`